# Create a sql variable and query other tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to query a table and get the results into a variable. With the variable results do another select query using the variable details as the filter.

So far:

```
DECLARE @storeIds int    
SET @storeIds = (SELECT StoreID FROM Store WHERE ParentStoreID=9)

--print @storeIds

SELECT c.FirstName, c.LastName, c.CustomerId, r.StoreID
FROM Consumer AS c
    INNER JOIN Purchases AS r ON c.CustomerId= r.CustomerId
WHERE r.StoreID = @storeIds
   -- (r.StoreID = 9) OR
   -- (r.StoreID = 10) OR
   -- (r.StoreID = 11)
GROUP BY c.FirstName, c.LastName, c.CustomerId, r.StoreID
ORDER BY c.FirstName
```

**I get an error:**

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you particularly want the `@StoreIds` variable elsewhere you could just amend your `WHERE` clause to:

```
WHERE r.StoreID IN (SELECT StoreID FROM Store WHERE ParentStoreID = 9)
```

Comment: Thanks Barry! I didnt know that I could create another select statement within a WHERE :(

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that multiple stores have the same `ParentStoreID`, so when you query, you are trying to put multiple values into your `INT` variable.

You could look at trying:

```
SELECT c.FirstName, c.LastName, c.CustomerId, p.StoreID
FROM Consumer AS c
INNER JOIN Purchases AS p ON c.CustomerId = p.CustomerId
INNER JOIN Store AS s ON p.StoreId = s.StoreId
WHERE s.ParentStoreID = 9
GROUP BY c.FirstName, c.LastName, c.CustomerId, r.StoreID
ORDER BY c.FirstName
```

This query should give you all the purchases you want, from all of the stores with `ParentStoreId = 9`.

Information about [JOINS](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html) might help you as well.

Answer (score 0):

Barry and Adam Wenger have the best approach, but to directly address the error, you can ensure that you are getting exactly one result while setting the variable by using the top 1 modifier.  Like:

```
DECLARE @storeIds int     
SET @storeIds = (SELECT top 1 StoreID FROM Store WHERE ParentStoreID=9)
```

Answer (score 0):

Can be done in different ways:

1. Using sub query

   ```
   SELECT c.FirstName, c.LastName, c.CustomerId, r.StoreID
   FROM Consumer AS c
      INNER JOIN Purchases AS r ON c.CustomerId= r.CustomerId
   WHERE r.StoreID = (SELECT StoreID FROM Store WHERE ParentStoreID=9)
   GROUP BY c.FirstName, c.LastName, c.CustomerId, r.StoreID
   ORDER BY c.FirstName
   ```
2. Using Join Operation

   ```
   SELECT c.FirstName, c.LastName, c.CustomerId, r.StoreID
   FROM Consumer AS c
       INNER JOIN Purchases AS r ON c.CustomerId= r.CustomerId 
       INNER JOIN (SELECT StoreID FROM Store WHERE ParentStoreID=9) AS s(StoreID)
           ON r.StoreID = s.StoreID
   GROUP BY c.FirstName, c.LastName, c.CustomerId, r.StoreID
   ORDER BY c.FirstName
   ```